# How to set a timeout to terminate nginx workers?

Tags: python, nginx, iis, uwsgi, pylons

I would like to set a duration for Nginx to terminate the workers after the timeout. I am looking for a feature like "Ping Maximum Response Time" in IIS. I am using uWSGI, Nginx, and Pylons Framework.

> IIS - Ping Maximum Response Time (seconds): Maximum time (in seconds)
> that a worker process is given to respond to a health monitoring ping.
> If the worker process does not respond, it is terminated.

I found some Nginx directives, but I am not sure which one(s) must be used.

- [uwsgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_read_timeout)
- [uwsgi_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_send_timeout)
- [proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)
- [proxy_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_send_timeout)
- [worker_shutdown_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_shutdown_timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

As Nginx is used as a reverse proxy, I added these three directives.

```
proxy_connect_timeout 90;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 600; # (in seconds) <- must be changed to what we need.
```